# Smashing C++ VPTRs

Tags: c++

I am taking a computer security class and I am reading http://phrack.org/issues/56/8.html.
In bo3.cpp the author creates his own VTABLE, and overwrites VPTR to point to his VTABLE.
To do this he needs the address of VTABLE, which - in this example - is the address of the object.
What is strange to me is that all this executed in the exploited code. I am a beginner, but I think that this technique can not be used in practice, because we can not edit the source code and recompile it. Is there any way to build the VTABLE and overwrite VPTR (for example with a buffer overflow) outside the code (without editing the vulnerable source code)?

Update: Let's say the vulnerable program asks for a string input, and I can overwrite with it the VPTR. I write my own code, creating a VTABLE in it, and printing the VTABLE address. I run my code and pass my VTABLE address (repeated enough times to overwrite the target VPTR) as the string input to the vulnerable program. Will this work? Is there a better/simpler way to do this?

Comment: If you can write to the target memory somehow (`WriteProcessMemory`, DLL injection and friends, buffer overflow, etc), then everything is possible (with varying degrees of complexity), even if you don't have the source code. If the target process cannot be written to in any way, then it's not possible.

Comment: Are you taking online C++ security class? Can you paste url?

Comment: @pranitkothari no, C++ vulnerabilities is my chosen topic for presentation.

Comment: @franz1 seeing as how this is pretty much what the PS3 USB Jailbreak did (doesn't really matter if it's C jump-tables or C++ VTABLEs), I'm fairly sure that this technique can be used in practise

Comment: You don't need to edit the source code. You can edit the executable in a hex editor, if you know where to look.

Comment: Dear downvoter, please explain shortly the reason you are downvoting. I would like to learn.

Comment: You might find https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/vtv interesting

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the technique.

Common way how dynamic polymorphism (virtual inheritance) is implemented in C++ is with hidden vtable pointer member. That member is then present in all objects that have virtual functions. It is most typically located at very beginning of object.

If a virtual function is called for object then the program calls a function from that pointed at vtable. So if you manage to overwrite the beginning of object with your data then you can make the vtable pointer to point anywhere else and achieve that something else is executed instead of a virtual member function.

It is impossible to use that exploit if the program has no permission to write to executable memory (or to execute writable memory) but that is not the case with majority of widespread operating systems.